# Confusion regarding emulator and simulator?

Tags: emulation, simulator

My head was bursting about the difference of emulator and simulator since some days.So i started to find out what they are.But i got some answers which are very contrasting.Somewhere i saw:

`The Simulator tries to duplicate the behavior of the device.
The Emulator tries to duplicate the inner workings of the device.`

and in another resource i saw:

`The goal of an emulation is to able to substitute for the object it is emulating.
A simulation’s focus is more on the modelling of the internal state of the target`

I am really a bit confused???

Answer (score 0):

### Emulator

Reproduce the precise behaviour of a system, generally all the way down to the hardware level. So, for example, the Android emulator pretends to be an actual ARM device, with virtualized hardware and a virtual ARM CPU. This provides the best realism and can run native ARM code, but often at a heavy speed penalty. The emulated environment is supposed to be so close to the real thing (modulo the slow speed) that it can substitute for the real thing in a lot of cases.

Another example of an emulator is most virtual machine software, which aims to provide a complete emulated computer system to run an operating system.

### Simulator

Simulate the behaviour of a target system by recreating its details at a higher level, e.g. by recompiling the OS or program for a new CPU and connecting it directly to the real hardware (instead of using emulated hardware). This is faster, but less accurate because it does not replicate the behaviour of the actual hardware. For example, the iOS simulator runs a subset of iOS, ported to x86. It can't run native ARM code, nor can it replicate hardware quirks unique to real iOS devices.